# Python: string to list

Tags: python

how to convert a sting of the format `"[u'logic', u'jackpot']"` into a list of the format `['logic', 'jackpot']`? 
Note: `"".split()` didn't work. It gave me: `["[u'logic',",
 "u'jackpot',", "u'420',", "u'pvp", "label',", "u'cassius", "cake',", "u'pod",
 "vlivem',", "u'EP',", "u'yzo',", "u'hank", "moody']"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **safe** `literal_eval` from `ast` like so:

```
from ast import literal_eval as leval

print(leval("[u'logic', u'jackpot']"))  # -> ['logic', 'jackpot']
```